# Json file for Canada's province

Tags: json, d3.js

I want to draw a map in d3 with geojson.
I did it for Canada's map.

Now i want to draw a map of every state of canada.
For e.g Nova scotia's map.
I searched a lot but i didnt got the co-ordinates of it.
Could you please give me its json file.

Comment: Oh, I see you asked a very similar question before. Duplicate questions aren't very good :/

Comment: Sahil you've literally asked the same question three times. This is bad practice on SO, and is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Canada has provinces, not states.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries/CAN.geo.json) is the json you are looking for.

Comment: I have this..it is of Canada..i want for a specific state only. I want for Nova Scotia.

Comment: I want province..
This time i am just asking the json file. I did not got a single answer in all. It is of much importance so i asked, but didnt got any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to Nova Scotia geometry in various formats, including geoJSON.
http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/239439.html

This site is a bit difficult to navigate, but if you look around you should be able
to get any other Canadian provinces you need as well.